# Powershell: -match seem to work wrong

Tags: xml, powershell, null, format, match

I am experimenting with powershell and xml. Unfortunately, I have a problem I don't understand. I try to test the value of node againt $Null. But it seems to give the wrong answer.

Here is what I do: file `xml.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <report>
  <row>
    <pProductNr>5128.10.00</pProductNr>
  </row>
 </report>
```

Then I am trying this:

```
[xml]$x=.\xml.xml
$x.report.row.pProductNr -match $Null
```

The result is then "True". But it looks not empty.
I am pretty new at powershell and it seems there is magic I haven't understood... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `-match` is meant for regex.  Not sure why you're trying to compare to `$Null`..

Comment: Thanks for the hint. –match is looking for something in the string. So, this is not want i wanted to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **read the contents of an XML file such as `xml.xml` into an XML DOM you must use `Get-Content`**:

```
[xml] $x = Get-Content -Raw .\xml.xml
```

You can then **use `.` notation to drill down into the document**, as you've attempted.

However, PowerShell's `-match` operator is designed to work with *regular expressions* passed as *strings*.
If you pass `$null`, Powershell stringifies that to `''`, the empty string, which amounts to a regular expression that matches *anything*.
Therefore, **`... -match $null` matches *anything* - and is therefore pointless.**
Generally, `-match` - unless explicitly anchored with `^` and `$` - matches *substrings* of the LHS.

**To test if an element's content is empty or doesn't exist**, simply use `-eq ''`:

```
 $x.report.row.pProductNr -eq ''
```

**Caveat**: If `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher is in effect, an attempt to reference a nonexistent property will cause an *error*.